# Mongoose devuelve documento sin información actualizada

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

He utilizado la función de Mongoose para actualizar un documento:

```
Modelo.findOneAndUpdate({foo:'bar'},{$set: {foo:'foo'}},(err, _modelo)=>{
    if(!err){
        console.log(_modelo);
    }        
})
```

Y lo que me imprime por consola es:

```
{  
  foo : 'bar'  
}
```

Es decir, me devuelve el documento con la información que poseía antes de ser actualizado. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

## He encontrado la solución.

Para que la función de actualización devuelva el documento actualizado se debe agregar como parametro a la consulta:

```
{new:true}
```

Tal y como lo muestra la documentación de [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate). De tal modo que el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
Modelo.findOneAndUpdate({foo:'bar'},{$set: {foo:'foo'}},{new:true},(err, _modelo)=>{
    if(!err){
        console.log(_modelo);
    }        
})
```

Y por ende devuelve el documento actualizado por consola:

```
{foo:'foo'}
```